# Google Earth Engine: Dropdown of items in ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a select menu which lists all datasets in an ImageCollection. When the user selects an item, the referenced dataset should be displayed in the map. Here's a static example that works and illustrates my approach so far...

Step 1 - Acquire L8 scenes for region of interest and create a list of what should be the label-value pairs for the select menu:

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(113, 53.5, 114, 54); 
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(roi);

var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
    .filterBounds(roi);

var sat_scene_dict = landsatCollection.map(function(sat_scene) {
  var dict = {
    value: sat_scene.id(),
    label: sat_scene.get('DATE_ACQUIRED'), 
  };
  return ee.Feature(sat_scene.geometry(), dict);
});
```

Step 2 - Initialize select items and populate with values

```js
var imageSelect = ui.Select({
  items: [ // Replace this part with labels/value from the list of scenes
    {label: '2013-06-16', value: 'LC08_128022_20130616'},
    {label: '2015-05-21', value: 'LC08_128023_20150521'}
  ], 
  onChange: function(value) {
    var selected_scene = 
        landsatCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', value));
    Map.addLayer(selected_scene, {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1']}, 'Selected scene');
  }
});
```

So, the whole problem is about how to populate the 'items' of `ui.Select` with label-value pairs from the list of scenes. As soon as I put any form of `sat_scene_dict` to items I get errors in in the form of `The argument provided to ui.List.reset() must be an array.`. I have tried to convert the `sat_scene_dict` to a list of dictionaries as in the static version but keep getting errors that `map` must return features or images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `sat_scene_dict` is a FeatureCollection (i.e. a remote not-yet-computed collection of features), not an array.

To initialize a `ui.Select` drop-down, you need a plain old JavaScript array, which you can get using the `getInfo()` method on FeatureCollection:

```js
var features = sat_scene_dict.getInfo()['features'];
var select_items = []
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  select_items.push({
    label: features[i]['properties']['label'],
    value: features[i]['properties']['value']
  })
}

var imageSelect = ui.Select({
  items: select_items,
  onChange: function(value) {
    var selected_scene = 
        landsatCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', value));
    Map.addLayer(selected_scene, {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1']}, 'Selected scene');
  }
});
```

`getInfo()` causes the FeatureCollection to be computed (aka materialized) and stored in a plain JavaScript object, from which you can extract whatever data you need.

Note: The `print` command is very useful for debugging these intermediate data types, e.g. `print(features)`.

Comment: i got the error: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node. If i delete the ['features'] in line 1 the error disappear but the select_items is now empty. What can i do?

Comment: I'd suggest calling `print(sat_scene_dict)` to make sure it is indeed a FeatureCollection or ImageCollection before trying to extract features from it.